Updated question about increasing the values in a dataset so that they cover as entirely as possible the continuum of some number
I posted similar question before, and want to re-post it with some additional details.
The date is:
data <- structure(list(country = c("Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
                       "Italy", "Italy", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                       "Austria", "Austria", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
                       "Germany", "Germany", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", 
                       "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                       "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway", 
                       "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
                       "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                       "France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
                       "Spain", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
                       "Portugal", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", 
                       "Poland", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", 
                       "Czech", "Czech", "Czech", "Czech", "Czech", "Czech", "Hungary", 
                       "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary"), date = c(1000, 
                                                                                        1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 
                                                                                        1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 
                                                                                        1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 
                                                                                        1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 
                                                                                        1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 
                                                                                        1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 
                                                                                        1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 
                                                                                        1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800), fit.0.025quant = c(0.769658840175483, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.2348464356932, 1.31495547349783, 0.719961329486957, 0.533187633507986, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.41237993202555, 0.356857796236969, 0.451661489951035, 0.397337695624864, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.409974403121542, 0.393472893048412, 0.287098718925738, 0.354883715712781, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.448886474450658, 0.39715908146481, 0.410487903703693, 0.395658067652691, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.29532573597963, 0.356128697768401, 0.424643741286452, 1.61932567884506, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.30548827584594, 2.76268553213141, 3.56905828257608, 0.376482568951331, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.48293037879362, 0.456032236653499, 0.576182569333386, 0.833933073149153, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.505329284288562, 0.353803982641129, 0.447057201802133, 0.406336078139197, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.412791109089504, 0.395171011307627, 0.288354069920872, 0.382168678659812, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.482002569482113, 0.755468540519089, 1.42716100547254, 1.96250491461143, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.10457588767127, 0.803868996482994, 1.37593437757613, 1.3439452894484, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.813514702370298, 0.91011173357764, 1.63924488873152, 0.580362444026788, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.934855991877621, 0.60121456278639, 0.534015226467462, 0.622887536264883, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.904806796706558, 0.353024270759662, 0.438686138447152, 0.685977522753906, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.17963934886268, 1.31914382834096, 1.28789209079277, 0.701713931393234, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.26972914823194, 1.90066571401692, 2.07177013841196, 1.93618111824184, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.992803246021283, 0.343613131108278, 0.430456920488114, 0.417579056383305, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.418671290357986, 0.402050606863924, 0.308364224621195, 0.583328703310094, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.918786031443329, 1.06376749897766, 0.655600082733113, 0.51395693234016, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.426788514799349, 0.555489913959345, 0.876131197255411, 0.590736399231011, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.48277052821614, 0.433796959718193, 0.329941536902841), fit.mean = c(1.44477219719004, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        2.08847795346887, 1.92074020692043, 1.32464829710997, 1.13796066089688, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.08343928221085, 1.0270630140043, 1.05528951308053, 0.976661348814801, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.988745362827999, 0.987479550023199, 0.964770050345412, 1.02449122893449, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.05015220962167, 0.976564469857287, 0.989147401032551, 0.989069619749544, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.970583787671834, 1.03847015147848, 1.06933995625971, 2.22488490046604, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        2.88660593193075, 3.36054537244564, 4.42004358638192, 1.04595162968831, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.08727301417595, 1.03638887686208, 1.1536166718476, 1.50053537077068, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.17627912933396, 1.02316037397786, 1.0471028064008, 0.984404683845781, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.991111655212924, 0.988737905272986, 0.965489841545364, 1.05099802550399, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.08432480769346, 1.37909032310489, 2.00490281582626, 2.63726205887859, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        2.84334982786008, 1.48411988883991, 2.15479009506574, 1.9287002282937, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.46182505532069, 1.56062168440954, 2.40992161620059, 1.25026845456292, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.58672045233699, 1.18288150111622, 1.12016814013165, 1.21698183308848, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.6429380910084, 1.02130662625173, 1.03621997583324, 1.27713301352629, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.77365203410072, 1.92492063997973, 1.96675791602409, 1.39766534448098, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.88778510186449, 2.58940980132166, 2.73324890368023, 2.56170704830504, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.83047658204545, 1.01151006076038, 1.02327754863757, 0.99485311187439, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.996288739427046, 0.994000331900843, 0.980075930151572, 1.25114729764489, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.6084916455723, 1.6886774938227, 1.23925646732008, 1.11166030345131, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.1008350449816, 1.22031434122474, 1.53062736345093, 1.16749661547219, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.05991033202474, 1.02338313757614, 0.99829580992981), fit.0.975quant = c(2.1467629708395, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.86800630410102, 2.51470712494928, 1.95333925576533, 1.77489115834241, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.7877280165075, 1.70378532556924, 1.66231397117297, 1.55641371966469, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.56640209717694, 1.57861036681008, 1.63693645172889, 1.69986070323533, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.65430128162006, 1.55628507271894, 1.5667605188449, 1.5799958764014, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.64125536079131, 1.73831613627608, 1.73284437119186, 2.8505231915393, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  3.4683315348823, 3.97299977634175, 5.16994639025026, 1.7298419269412, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.70332798100424, 1.62358809814901, 1.73503460780531, 2.1309767822864, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.85862536193042, 1.69808462301802, 1.65012962012338, 1.5629733104483, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.56855801488705, 1.57970304136785, 1.63743275050033, 1.74180211662632, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.71027755854349, 2.03181318141753, 2.58279095091443, 3.26695568561824, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  3.52780543298105, 2.20237329589412, 2.88519836047102, 2.50741694603542, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.14275125784703, 2.2512588191423, 3.12462265816526, 1.94809249419394, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.20744185138983, 1.77512404032398, 1.72085964175628, 1.82622191471393, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.33007667194589, 1.69788616480218, 1.64224392607015, 1.88459325405899, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.35615418597892, 2.51705325980683, 2.63321977331943, 2.14835481116668, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.48812497421984, 3.23679202898418, 3.36053476964815, 3.16592918332051, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.78811525721561, 1.68210669163609, 1.61753862767797, 1.57246161300083, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.5735230229861, 1.58459708632124, 1.64902261852296, 1.93733077288017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.24895076383125, 2.29176328616676, 1.83579531693941, 1.73333081545444, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.81135126517726, 1.90284502294021, 2.15299250030576, 1.74961986136672, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.64322805676024, 1.61840886544359, 1.67093316282806)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -84L))

The question is the following:
For Italy in date ‘1000’, the values for ‘fit.0.025quant’, fit.mean’ and ‘fit.0.975quant’ are 0.7696588, 1.4447722 and 2.146763, respectively. The highest number that currently lies within their boundaries is 2. I want all three values to get lifted, so that they cover as entirely as possible the continuum between 2.01-2.99.
And so should happen for every row in a dataset. For example, for Italy in date ‘1200’, the values for ‘fit.0.025quant’, fit.mean’ and ‘fit.0.975quant’ are 1.2348464, 2.0884780 and 2.868006, respectively. The highest number that currently lies within their boundaries is 2. I want all three values to get lifted, so that they cover as entirely as possible the continuum between 2.01-2.99.
So it is like lifting ‘fit.0.025quant’, fit.mean’ and‘fit.0.975quant’ to the uppermost number that currently lies within their boundaries, so that all three cover as entirely as possible the continuum of that number.
Preferrably, the results should not be like '1.2', '1.4', 1.6', but be stretched over the continuum of 1, 1.01-1.99.
In my previous question, Zephryl suggested a code:
add <- apply(data[, 3:5], 1, \(x) floor(max(x))) - apply(data[, 3:5], 1, min)
add <- ifelse(add < -0.01, 0, add + 0.01)
data[, 3:5] <- data[, 3:5] + add

The excerpt from the results:
new.data <- structure(list(country = c("Italy", "Italy", "Italy"), date = structure(1:3, levels = c("1000", 
                                                                                    "1200", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800"), class = "factor"), democracy = c(1.34436508740733, 
                                                                                                                                                              3.99, 2.99), fit.0.025quant = c(1.01, 3.01, 2.01), fit.mean = c(1.99, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              3.48392980663905, 2.87661379777081), fit.0.975quant = c(2.1467629708395, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.86800630410102, 2.51470712494928)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

This leads to some values to weirdly get shrunk (like the values of Italy in 1200).
Guys, I hope my explanations are not confusing.
Do you think there can be a suitable code that automatically transforms the values in a whole dataset as expected?

What do you mean by “lifted” and “ cover as entirely as possible the continuum of that number”? How do you want the final numbers to be chosen? At random? Using some algorithm? If so, what is the algorithm? And I’m guessing that when you write “number” you mean “integer”? Sadly, I feel this question is no clearer than your previous one.

So if three values are 0.7696588, 1.4447722 and 2.146763, the highest INTEGER (yes, you are right) that currently lies within their boundaries is 2.  The final output has to be like '2,01', '2,62' and '2,95'. As a result, the three values cover as entirely as possible the continuum of 2,01-2,99

We can start by finding the ratio between the top value we want to fit (fit.0.975quant) and the bottom value (fit.0.025quant). After scaling, we want these to be 0.98 apart (the distance from 0.01 to 0.99). So if the top number in one row were double the bottom one, we want to find what number would squeeze that 2.000 to 0.9800. The formula gives us 2.041 for that number -- and sure enough, 2.000 / 2.041 = 0.9800.
We can then use that coefficient for each row to rescale the distance from the 0.025quant to each mean and 0.975quant figure so they are at most 0.98 away. That's what we can add to where we've put the 0.025quant points (floored + 0.01).
library(dplyr)
data |>
  mutate(scale = fit.0.975quant/fit.0.025quant / 0.98,
         fit.0.025quant_scaled = floor(fit.0.975quant) + 0.01,
         fit.mean_scaled = fit.0.025quant_scaled + fit.mean/fit.0.025quant/scale,
         fit.0.975quant_scaled = fit.0.025quant_scaled + fit.0.975quant/fit.0.025quant/scale)

Result
       country date fit.0.025quant  fit.mean fit.0.975quant    scale fit.0.025quant_scaled fit.mean_scaled fit.0.975quant_scaled
1        Italy 1000      0.7696588 1.4447722       2.146763 2.846163                  2.01        2.669540                  2.99
2        Italy 1200      1.2348464 2.0884780       2.868006 2.369960                  2.01        2.723635                  2.99
3        Italy 1500      1.3149555 1.9207402       2.514707 1.951418                  2.01        2.758527                  2.99
4        Italy 1600      0.7199613 1.3246483       1.953339 2.768487                  1.01        1.674583                  1.99
5        Italy 1700      0.5331876 1.1379607       1.774891 3.396766                  1.01        1.638321                  1.99
6        Italy 1800      0.4123799 1.0834393       1.787728 4.423620                  1.01        1.603922                  1.99
7      Austria 1000      0.3568578 1.0270630       1.703785 4.871847                  1.01        1.600756                  1.99
8      Austria 1200      0.4516615 1.0552895       1.662314 3.755553                  1.01        1.632135                  1.99
9      Austria 1500      0.3973377 0.9766613       1.556414 3.997047                  1.01        1.624957                  1.99
...

The chart below is a visual demonstration of how the input values are transformed into scaled values as specified in the OP.


dude, could you briefly explain why you picked 'fit.0.975quant' and 'fit.0.025quant' in the first row of your code (I mean 'scale = fit.0.975quant/fit.0.025quant / 0.98')? And what does '0.98' mean?

Explanation added to the answer.
